# Get Object from specific Bucket on AWS S3 in Mule 4

Tags: amazon-s3, mule, mule-connector

I want to read a file (object) from S3 bucket in Mule 4.
I have access to read/write file only to this bucket. Hence when I enter access key & secret in global config of AWS S3 connector and do 'Test connection', I am getting Access Denied error.

The way we can access in WinSCP is using remote directory option from Advanced tab. There we are giving bucket name and then we can get access to this specific bucket.

I tried providing "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name" in Custom Service Endpoint under Advance tab of S3 global config. But it throws error like below :
*The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: ZESE26MHAX5EP13G, Extended Request ID: jIji2hGErWw+oiaFsXOhHS4DFB5v44e9qSbkF+6ifqq8xTqn1Hde2hPRkiG9bW8vkSoXyg98bQ0=)*

Not sure how to achieve in Mule using S3 connector.

Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: Does not have option for remote directory. I tried with "Custom Service Endpoint". But with that I am getting error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Comment: The question is not clear and doesn't has focus. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. How to read a 'directory'? You should provide the code and errors you are having. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And edit your questions to add details.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest version of S3 connector bucket should not have "/" and folder name.

Due to behavior in the S3 SDK, this error occurs when the folder name is put in the "Bucket name" field.

Ref : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001121867&type=1